# Turtle inner circle boundary in python

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Okay, I've been at this all day and haven't a clue. I need to get my turtle object to draw random lines *outside* of a circle.

I've made code that restricts the random lines within the boundaries before, so I thought all I had to do was change the sign, but that didn't work. I'm not allowed to use coordinate geometry - it has to be something more basic...

Here's my code in it's current format:

```
import turtle, random
mRoshi = turtle.Turtle()

def draw_any_shape(myTurtle, sideLength, numSides):
    turnAng = 360/numSides
    for i in range(numSides):
        myTurtle.forward(sideLength)
        myTurtle.right(turnAng)

def drawCircle(myTurtle, radius, startX, startY):
    circumference = 2*3.1415*radius
    sideLength = circumference/360
    myTurtle.penup()
    myTurtle.goto(startX, startY)
    #myTurtle.dot()
    myTurtle.goto(startX, startY+radius)
    myTurtle.pendown()
    draw_any_shape(myTurtle, sideLength, 360)


def stumblingTurtle(myTurtle, radius, startX, startY, paramN5):
    circumference = 2*3.1415*radius
    myTurtle.speed(6)
    drawCircle(myTurtle, radius, startX, startY)
    myTurtle.penup()
    for i in range(paramN5):
        drx = random.randint(-800, 800)
        drw = random.randint(-800, 800)
        if (drx**2 + drw**2) > radius**2:
            myTurtle.goto(drx,drw)
        crx = random.randint(-800, 800)
        crw = random.randint(-800, 800)
        xdif = crx-drx
        ydif = crw-drw
        for j in range(drx, crx):
            for k in range(drw, crw):
                if (xdif**2 + ydif**2) > radius**2:
                    myTurtle.goto(crx,crw)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?  It's also based on code that originally [kept the turtle within a circle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452311/turtlegraphics-python-constraining-random-moving-turtle-in-a-circle/40967276#40967276).  It uses Python3 turtle's *undo* capability to allow the turtle to accidentally wander into the circle and then undo that accident as if it never happened:

```
import turtle
import random

RADIUS = 50
MAXIMUM_TURN = 45
STEP_SIZE = 10
BORDER = 20

def bounded_random_move():

    yertle.forward(STEP_SIZE)

    x, y = yertle.position()

    if (x * x + y * y) < RADIUS * RADIUS or x < -window_width/2 or x > window_width/2 or y < -window_height/2 or y > window_height/2:
        yertle.undo()  # undo misstep
        turn = random.randint(180 - MAXIMUM_TURN, 180 + MAXIMUM_TURN)
        yertle.left(turn)

    turtle.ontimer(bounded_random_move, 100)

turtle.setup(RADIUS * 10, RADIUS * 10)

window_width = turtle.window_width() - BORDER
window_height = turtle.window_height() - BORDER

magic_marker = turtle.Turtle(visible=False)
magic_marker.penup()
magic_marker.color("red")
magic_marker.sety(-RADIUS)
magic_marker.pendown()
magic_marker.circle(RADIUS)

yertle = turtle.Turtle(shape="turtle", visible=False)
yertle.speed("fastest")
yertle.penup()
yertle.goto(RADIUS * 2, RADIUS * 2)  # start outside circle
yertle.pendown()
yertle.showturtle()

turtle.ontimer(bounded_random_move, 100)

turtle.exitonclick()
```

My undo trick might not be rigorous enough for everyone, however.

[image]

Comment: Okay, I like what you did, but, when I attempted to adapt your code to mine (for the assignment), it still crossed. Maybe I'm oversimplifying it, but all I did was get rid of everything after crw then adding your first if condition (I couldn't get the code to display properly in the comments).

Comment: Could you explain to me your bounded_random_move function?

Comment: @PolitEcon2016, the `bounded_random_move()` function makes a step forward in the current direction.  It tests if that wasn't a good idea (i.e. did we step into the circle or off the boundaries of the window).  If it was a bad idea, it undoes it (putting it's position back to before the move) and does a U-turn (but doesn't move forward.)  Regardless of good or bad move, it then makes an additional slight turn (stumbling effect) and sets off a timer for another call to this function in 100ms.  Let me know what part of that you'd like described in finer detail.

Comment: Okay, got it. I realize I wasn't clear in my code, but I do not intend for the turtle to "stumble", but instead walk straight but random paths. Essentially, just jump from point A to point B without specifying a turn angle. Is that possible or must there be a turn angle at those limits? Also, is there any way to do it without using screen?

And by the way, the undo function works almost well in your code but does not in mine...

Comment: @PolitEcon2016, I've eliminated the stumble which was a minor edit you should be able to make yourself.  As far as a distant point vs. an angle, they both serve the same purpose and you should be able to switch the code from one to the other.  As far as not using 'screen', I've done that as well but all that's changed is screen is being used implicitly rather than explicitly and that's not really an improvement.